# Datagrid using div in a struts web application

Tags: jquery, datagrid, struts

i want to create a datagrid using div tag in a struts web application. Is it possible?

please help me

thanks

Comment: yes its possible! go through the documentation and try to do something, if you get stuck somewhere come to this place and put the code and the issue where you got stuck.

Comment: can u please provide me with some links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to create a `datagrid` using `div` tags, it does not matter if it is a `struts` web application or `spring` or any other framework based web application.

If you want to use `struts` specific components in creating the `datagrid`, you can use `struts tag library descriptors` that provides this feature.
For instance if you include `struts-layout.tld` you can use `<layout:datagrid>` to achive this.

You can implement `datagrid` using `jquery` [a javascript plugin] . Try this http://www.datatables.net/

See this link that list the various `jquery plugins` for implementing `datagrid`:
http://jquerygrip.blogspot.com/2012/11/best-jquery-grid-plugins-and-jquery-tables.html
http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/

Since you mentioned about using `<div>` tags, please note that almost all the `jquery plugins` use `div` tags.

Please try this, and if you are stuck while doing so, share the details of what you tried, and where you need help exactly. People here will definitely help you out.